# How Can I Call Another Ant Created Testing Suite From Any Target

Tags: java, ant

```
<target name="Regression_Test" depends="displayEnvironment">
        <property name="TestSuite" value="RegressioonTestSuite.xml"/>
        <ant antfile="TestNG.xml" dir="${tools.loc}" target="runTestNG" inheritAll="true"/>
        <!--<antcall target="buildAndTest"  inheritAll="true"/>-->      
    </target>
```

In Above Code..

```
<property name="TestSuite" value="RegressioonTestSuite.xml"/>
```

Is Not Working, It does not pass to `RegreessionTestSuite.xml`

Created a file for regression testing Named as `RegreessionTestSuite.xml`

if i write

this code outside of target then it works but inside any target it won't

Comment: I guess you are still forming the question.. as I don't see any code

Comment: What is the build error on console?

Comment: hi actually there is no build error..

Comment: then paste the console output. "this code outside of target then it works but inside any target it won't" means by running <ant outside the target?
If yes, can you also confirm what is "displayEnvironment" task doing?

Answer (score 0):

as per comments above, it would be helpful if you could post the error/exception you are getting.
In the meanwhile, a few tips to debug it could be:

- call ant via the exec task (you can also do an echo of the command you are executing, to double check for typos etc.)
- are the target you want to invoke in a different file? is this file 'imported' into your master build file?

Comment: please check i have added more info of problem

Comment: I'm assuming it's just a typo, but bust in case: are you aware that you mentioned in one case Regressio**o**nTestSuite.xml and in another Regr**e**essionTestSuite.xml? Also, could you execute an echo within your Regression_Test target and output the value of ${tools.loc} and of ${TestSuite} ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your support..

I am newer in Ant

Found Solution...Made a silly mistake

```
    <ant antfile="TestNG.xml" dir="${tools.loc}" target="runTestNG" inheritAll="true">
         <property name="TestSuite" value="RegressioonTestSuite.xml"/>
    </ant>
```